# zip works in terminal, but not inside script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip

I'm writing a bash script based on zenity that allows the user to choose files to compress and compresses them using zip.
The problem is that whenever I get to the "zipping" part, it doesn't work. On the other hand, when I write the exact same command straight into the terminal, everything goes fine and the new zip file appears.

Of course I do have `#!/bin/bash` on the top of my script code.
I've tried two kinds of commands, with quotation marks and apostrophes (in the terminal apostrophes allow multiple-word file names, while quotation marks only work with one-word file names), but none work. This is how I use the commands:

The commands:

```
    zip 'file name.zip' '/home/user/filetozip.txt'
    zip "file name.zip" "/home/user/filetozip.txt"
```

Both options leave me with this (of course one prints apostrophes and the other one quotation marks):

```
    zip warning: name not matched: name.zip'
    zip warning: name not matched: '/home/user/filetozip.txt'
    zip error: Nothing to do! ('file.zip)
```

As I said before, the apostrophe option works perfectly when typed into the terminal, whether I use one-word file names or not; the one with quotation marks only works with one-word file names. I have no idea why the script always outputs these errors.

Ideally, I would like the script to allow multiple-word file names, but if anyone can provide me with the answer at least for one-word file names, I will be grateful too.

---

Here is the part of the script responsible for compressing:

```
    FILE=`zenity --file-selection --title "Choose the file for compression"`
    NAME=`zenity --entry --title "File name" --text "Enter the name for the zip file:"`
    zenity --question --title "Encryption" --text="Do you want your zip file to be password protected?" --ok-label="Yes" --cancel-label="No" --width 230
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
       PASS=`zenity --password --title "Password" --text "Enter password:" --width 250`
       while [[ -z $PASS ]]; do
       zenity --error --title "Error" --text "Empty password" --width 200
       PASS=`zenity --password --title "Password" --text "Enter password:" --width 250`
       done
       #zip with password
       ODP="-P ${PASS} '${NAME}.zip' '${FILE}'"
    else #zip without password
       ODP="'${NAME}.zip' '${FILE}'"
    fi
    zip $ODP
```

Comment: Can you `set -x` and run the script and post the output?

Comment: @BlackPearl what do you mean by setting -x? Do you mean running the script in the terminal like `script.sh -x`?

Comment: `sh -x script.sh`. You error is most likely because of the `'${NAME}.zip'` parameter.

Comment: @BlackPearl I get the variables that I initialize line after line, like this: `+ FILE=`, one line connected to getopts (which I use to display help with -h and info with -v) and then one syntax error: `scrypt.sh: 33: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")` which isn't connected to the compressing part, it's in the beginning, where I have a "while" loop displaying a zenity window for the user to choose options (also looking at the code I cannot see the "(" as a syntax error to be honest and this part of the script works fine).

Comment: You need to use arrays, instead of just strings.

Comment: Shellcheck produces [9 findings for your code](https://pastebin.com/WBiRLSna). You should fix them before continuing. Next, checkout the command syntax for the command. `zip 'file name.zip' '/home/user/filetozip.txt'` is not correct for the `zip` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you check your code first through https://www.shellcheck.net to avoid common shell problems.

Since shell script chokes on white space characters, an array should be preferred here. This preserves the actual strings.

```
  FILE=$(zenity --file-selection --title "Choose the file for compression")
    NAME=$(zenity --entry --title "File name" --text "Enter the name for the zip file:")
    zenity --question --title "Encryption" --text="Do you want your zip file to be password protected?" --ok-label="Yes" --cancel-label="No" --width 230
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
       PASS=$(zenity --password --title "Password" --text "Enter password:" --width 250)
       while [[ -z $PASS ]]; do
       zenity --error --title "Error" --text "Empty password" --width 200
       PASS=$(zenity --password --title "Password" --text "Enter password:" --width 250)
       done
       #zip with password
       ODP=(-P "${PASS}" "${NAME}".zip "${FILE}")
    else #zip without password
       ODP=("${NAME}.zip" "${FILE}")
    fi
    zip "${ODP[@]}"
```